# How do i skip a row from a CSV based on the value of 2 fields within the CSV file?

Tags: 8, migrations, plugins

I have a CSV file that contains about 200 records/rows.

**ID, OrgID, EstabID, OrgName, Address**

```
1, AB234, AB234, ABC corp, 123 Main Street
2, AB234, 8989, ABC Corp-West, 456 Better Street
3, 4858, CD323, First Tech Org, 9087 East Birdway
```

I would like to get the value of OrgID and EstabID and and if they are the same then id like to do something in a custom plugin like add the row to the migration or omit the current row to the migration. (If no plugin already exist)

**1, AB234, AB234, ABC corp, 123 Main Street**

I may be missing something but I cannot seem to find this type of functionality in one of the "process plugins" provided by Core or Migration Plus.

So to sum things up, how do you get the value of two fields and do something with those fields in a process plugin, if not then is there a similar functionality already in core i could build on?